# How can I call a method from an imported component on click?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Assuming I have the following two classes. Is it possible to call a method from the other class?

Here I'd like to call the method `App.changeColor` from `ColorBox`. But it does not seem to be working. When I click a color box, nothing will happen, even the alert is not outputted.

When I use `()`, the compiling fails:

`_App__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.changeColor is not a function`

ColorBox.js

```js
import React from 'react'

/* _____________________ Styles _____________________ */
import './App.css'
/* __________________________________________________ */

/* ___________________ Components ___________________ */
import App from './App'
/* __________________________________________________ */

class ColorBox extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="color-box" onClick={App.changeColor} style={{backgroundColor: this.props.bg}}></div>
        )
    }
}

export default ColorBox
```

App.js

```js
import React from 'react'

/* _____________________ Styles _____________________ */
import './App.css'
/* __________________________________________________ */

/* ___________________ Components ___________________ */
import ColorBox from './ColorBox';
/* __________________________________________________ */

class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        color: ["blue", "red", "yellow", "green", "purple", "indigo", "grey", "pink"]
    }

    changeColor = () => {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.color.length);
        this.props.bg = this.state.color[random];
        alert("lol");
    }

    randomizeColor() {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.color.length);
        return (random, this.state.color[random]);
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div className="App">
            <ColorBox bg={this.randomizeColor()} />
            <ColorBox bg={this.randomizeColor()} />
            <ColorBox bg={this.randomizeColor()} />
            <ColorBox bg={this.randomizeColor()} />
            <ColorBox bg={this.randomizeColor()} />
            <ColorBox bg={this.randomizeColor()} />
            <ColorBox bg={this.randomizeColor()} />
            <ColorBox bg={this.randomizeColor()} />
            <ColorBox bg={this.randomizeColor()} />
            <ColorBox bg={this.randomizeColor()} />
            <ColorBox bg={this.randomizeColor()} />
            <ColorBox bg={this.randomizeColor()} />
            <ColorBox bg={this.randomizeColor()} />
            <ColorBox bg={this.randomizeColor()} />
            <ColorBox bg={this.randomizeColor()} />
            <ColorBox bg={this.randomizeColor()} />
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

Updated (Functional Component):

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function App(){

    const [allColors, setAllColors] = useState(["blue", "red", "yellow", "green", "purple", "indigo", "grey", "pink"]);
    const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState(16);

    const randomizeColor = () => {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * allColors.length);
        return allColors[random];
    }

    const changeColor = () => {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * allColors.length);
        alert(allColors[random]);
    }

    const drawBoxes = () => {
        let n = 0;
        let drawBoxes = [];
        while (n < boxes) {
            drawBoxes.push(
            <div className="color-box" onClick={changeColor} style={{backgroundColor: randomizeColor()}} />
            );
            n++;
        }
        return drawBoxes;
    }

    return (
    <div className="App">
        {drawBoxes()}
    </div>
    ) }

export default App
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53499361/how-do-i-call-a-method-from-another-class-component-in-react-js

Comment: Looks like you are also mutating one of your props...don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the changeColor method as a prop to `ColorBox` Component.

```
<ColorBox changeColor={this.changeColor} .../>
```

Then you got the method as a prop in ColorBox component:

```js
function ColorBox({bg, changeColor}){

        return (
            <div className="color-box" 
                 onClick={changeColor} 
                 style={{backgroundColor: bg}}/>
        )
    
}
```

Some tips:

- Both components can be functions component without class, this the usual way to create components today, especially your ColorBox component who only have the render method. I changed it to that.
- If you only have a div without content, in jsx you can close the element in inline way, you don't need to create a close tag.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Could you take a look at the updated section in my initial posting? I still don't find a proper logic to on the one hand initialize the background-color for each object, but on the other hand to also change this by clicking. Do you have any idea?